# Rails: has_one relationship that can be direct or require a :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship, has-one, has-one-through

In my rails app, I have a relationship that can be either a has_one or a has_one :through, and I'm not sure how to architect this.

In other words, say I have the classes Foo, Bar, and Baz, the relationship between Foo and Baz could either be:

```
class Foo
  has_one :baz
end

class Baz
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

OR it could be

```
class Foo
  has_one :bar
  has_one :baz, through: :bar
end

class Bar
  has_one :baz
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Baz
 belongs_to :bar
end
```

Does anyone know what the best way is to manage both relationships?

Comment: Do you actually need an entirely different class or could you use a self-referencing has_one relationship(slef-joins)?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: What do you mean by `OR` here? What does it depends on?

Comment: it depends on how Baz was created. Baz could have been created either directly from a Foo instance or via a Bar instance. @BroiSatse

Comment: @ruby_newbie Yes the Bar class is necessary - it represents data that is important to the app. The issue is that a Baz, when created could belong to either a Bar or a Foo.

Comment: Sounds like you need a polymorphic association.

Comment: @ruby_newbie that doesn't work because what's really important is the Baz to Foo relationship, which can happen directly or via a Bar instance